# What is the acceleration profile of a cheetah?

Tags: bio-mechanics

I'm interested in the time it takes for a cheetah to reach maximum velocity as well as the acceleration over time that's typical of a cheetah prior to attaining this peak velocity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a recent paper published on *Nature*, cheetahs can reach a top speed of 29ms<sup>-1</sup> and very impressive accelerations, up to 100ms<sup>-2</sup>:

> The mean top speed was 14.9 +- 3.4ms<sup>-1</sup> and was usually only sustained for 1–2 s. The highest speed we recorded was a stride-averaged 25.9<sup>-1</sup>

Also impressive are the lateral accelerations:

> Hunts involved considerable manoeuvring, with maximum lateral (centripetal) accelerations often exceeding 13ms<sup>-2</sup>

Here is the acceleration and speed chart:

[image]

The paper has several other charts: [Locomotion dynamics of hunting in wildcheetahs](http://www.nature.com/articles/nature12295.epdf?referrer_access_token=FgrqpqkppfVBS6AZODb6GNRgN0jAjWel9jnR3ZoTv0O7ahBTtZssM3krLKqcPMkSgdyQ7sPillTHu4SFCILqD6NyK6Un_aALymf0V0lNmgJPDTwNg9t5C8PHOu26xArgEPW71lK2E50bFN-_tWk2F3SKXA69vdqLi9N-R_LhBbjPKP5Dets7ymZMbFZm9zNq&tracking_referrer=www.bbc.com)

Comment: That's interesting. But, what about the cheetah's acceleration profile?

Comment: The paper has a chart, but without precise values for the accelerations (given in "g", 9.8ms^-2). Check figure 2-f and figure 3-d.

Comment: I have. The chart is too small for eyes to perceive and it's on the scale of days not seconds...They were interested in the cheetah's hunting patterns.

Comment: Days? the x-axis is time in seconds. I edited the answer with the chart, check it.